# JavaScript, asp.net and Sql Server

Tags: javascript, c#-2.0, database-connection

I know how to use client side JavaScript with asp.net script. But I am unable to figure out how to retrieve data from database and show that data with JavaScript in an asp.net page.

Suppose I have written a JavaScript Grid. Then how can I fill that grid with data from SQL Server and show that grid on an asp.net page?

**That is, how to connect C# and JavaScript on the server side?**

I would be grateful if you provide me with an web-link of an example.

Hope I am able to articulate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to connect C# and JavaScript on
>   the server side

You can use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for this. It can issue a request to the server and after completion of the request response can be read in JavaScript in many formats like [HTML, XML](http://javascript.about.com/library/blajax08.htm), [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Can you provide me with an web link of an example?